# How to keep jquery selector alive after ajax refresh

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-selectors, asprepeater

I need a solution for the following problem.

I am using jquery odd selector to add a css to every odd item in a asp:repeater.

$(".item:odd").attr("class", "item odd");

After I do an ajax call (from updatepanel) to go to the next page in the repeater the classes aren't added to the items on the next page.

$(document).ajaxComplete doesn't seem to do the trick.

Any ideas?

Many thanks,

Arnoud

Comment: what about adding `$(".item:odd").attr("class", "item odd");` to your success callback?

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
$(".item:odd").attr("class", "item odd");
```

Inside the success callback for your ajax request

Comment: Ajax is handled by my codebehind so I'm guessing I can't do this?

Comment: I have found the solution. When using ajax with an updatepanel you can use pageLoad. It will trigger every time, even when you do ajaxcall...

function pageLoad(sender, args) { 
    ... 
}

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to add to the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);
    }

    function endRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        $(".item:odd").attr("class", "item odd");
    }
</script>
```

The content of the endRequestHandler will run after each AJAX request.

You will probably also need to add a ScriptManager to the page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
```